# Getting a StructType output for calculating distribution from a list

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

### The problem:

I have a column with a list of redundant values, which I need to be converted into a dictionary-like format in a new column of a PySpark dataframe.

The scenario:

Here's my PySpark dataframe:

| A | C | all_classes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | RDK | [1, 1, 1, 2, 2] |
| 10 | USW | [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2] |
| 8 | RDK | [21, 21, 21, 21, 20] |
| 8 | RDJ | [20, 20, 21] |
| 10 | RDK | [45, 45, 45, 45, 2, 2, 2] |
| 7 | SSW | [6, 6, 6, 19, 19] |

which I created using below line:

```
my_df.groupBy(['A', 'C']).agg(collect_list("Class").alias("all_classes"))
```

Now that I want a new column that will collate data as follows:
Consider the data of 1'st row from the above column: `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2]`

That needs to be converted into `{1: 3, 2: 2}` which is basically the number itself and no. of times it is duplicated.

### My attempt:

Since, I'm good with python I chose to go with writing a UDF something like this:

```
custom_collect_function = udf(lambda li: {k: li.count(k) for k in set(li)}, StructType(li, ArrayType(elementType=IntegerType()), False))

display(my_df.withColumn("Distribution", custom_collect_function(my_df.all_classes)))
```

I'm clearly failing to set the StructType here and I welcome any other/optimized approach than this. I also welcome any Spark way approach to the same.

The expected output:

| A | C | Distribution | all_classes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | RDK | {1: 3, 2: 2} | [1, 1, 1, 2, 2] |
| 10 | USW | {1: 1, 2: 6} | [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2] |
| 8 | RDK | {21: 4, 20: 1} | [21, 21, 21, 21, 20] |
| 8 | RDJ | {20: 2, 21: 1} | [20, 20, 21] |
| 10 | RDK | {45: 4, 2: 3} | [45, 45, 45, 45, 2, 2, 2] |
| 7 | SSW | {6: 3, 19: 2} | [6, 6, 6, 19, 19] |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually preferable to do it in the first groupby when you created the list `all_classes` from the original `my_df`:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn("cnt", F.count("*").over(Window.partitionBy("A", "C", "Class"))) \
    .groupBy("A", "C") \
    .agg(
    F.map_from_entries(
        F.collect_set(F.struct(F.col("Class"), F.col("cnt")))
    ).alias("Distribution"),
    F.collect_list("Class").alias("all_classes"),
)

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+---+---+-------------------------+----------------------------------------+
#|A  |C  |Distribution             |all_classes                             |
#+---+---+-------------------------+----------------------------------------+
#|7  |SSW|[6 -> 3, 19 -> 2]        |[19, 19, 6, 6, 6]                       |
#|8  |RDK|[20 -> 1, 21 -> 4]       |[20, 21, 21, 21, 21]                    |
#|10 |RDK|[2 -> 5, 1 -> 3, 45 -> 4]|[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 45, 45, 45, 45]|
#|8  |RDJ|[20 -> 2, 21 -> 1]       |[21, 20, 20]                            |
#|10 |USW|[2 -> 6, 1 -> 1]         |[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]                   |
#+---+---+-------------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Here, we count the number of occurrences of each class using a Window then group by `A` and `C` to create `all_classes` as you've already done but also creating `Distribution` as map column from the count column and the class using `map_from_entries` function. You can use later `to_json` on the map column if you want json string.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

result = my_df.withColumn(
    'all_classes',
    F.collect_list('Class').over(Window.partitionBy('A', 'C'))
).groupBy(
    'A', 'C', 'all_classes', 'Class'
).agg(
    F.count('Class').alias('cnt_class')
).groupBy(
    'A', 'C', 'all_classes'
).agg(
    F.map_from_entries(
        F.collect_list(F.struct('Class', 'cnt_class'))
    ).alias('distribution')
)

result.show(truncate=False)
+---+---+----------------------------------------+-------------------------+
|A  |C  |all_classes                             |distribution             |
+---+---+----------------------------------------+-------------------------+
|7  |SSW|[6, 6, 6, 19, 19]                       |[6 -> 3, 19 -> 2]        |
|8  |RDK|[21, 21, 21, 21, 20]                    |[21 -> 4, 20 -> 1]       |
|10 |RDK|[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 45, 45, 45, 45, 2, 2, 2]|[1 -> 3, 2 -> 5, 45 -> 4]|
|8  |RDJ|[20, 20, 21]                            |[20 -> 2, 21 -> 1]       |
|10 |USW|[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]                   |[1 -> 1, 2 -> 6]         |
+---+---+----------------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

The results are a bit different because somehow your grouped dataframe consists of duplicate rows with `(A, C) = (10, RDK)`. Also note that I used a MapType. Getting a StructType is not possible because the structs have to have the same fields in a given column, which is not true in this case.